# Ripple animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do that when I hold the mouse button (`mousedown`) so the scale stays and does not disappear. But everything what I tried ... doesn't work :(. So can you help me with that.

Here is my code:

```js
var count = 0;
$(".rippleAnimation").mousedown(function(e) {
  var time = new Date;
  md_time = time.getTime();

  // Setup
  var posX = $(this).offset().left,
    posY = $(this).offset().top,
    buttonWidth = $(this).width(),
    buttonHeight = $(this).height();

  // Add the element
  $(this).append("<span id='ripple" + count + "'></span>");


  // Make it round!
  if (buttonWidth >= buttonHeight) {
    buttonHeight = buttonWidth;
  } else {
    buttonWidth = buttonHeight;
  }

  // Get the center of the element
  var x = e.pageX - posX - buttonWidth / 2;
  var y = e.pageY - posY - buttonHeight / 2;

  /*var x = 0;
  var y = 0;*/

  // Add the ripples CSS and start the animation
  $("#ripple" + count).css({
    width: buttonWidth,
    height: buttonHeight,
    top: y + 'px',
    left: x + 'px'
  }).addClass("ripple rippleEffect");

  // Remove any old one
  //remove(count, default_animation_time);

  count++;
});
```

```css
.top {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FF9800;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ripple {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}

.rippleEffect {
  -webkit-animation: rippleDrop .6s linear;
  animation: rippleDrop .6s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rippleDrop {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rippleDrop {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#top">
  <div class="top rippleAnimation">
  </div>
</a>
```

Thanks for your help all :)

Comment: add forwards to the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` property ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)) your animation will end at the final keyframe. This should help you achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I am trying make that when you hold the mouse button, animation will stay on scale(2), but now when you hold the mouse button animation duration is 0.6s, so after 0.6s scale(0)

Comment: @Dolis change `linear` to `forwards` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode). This will point you in the right direction I think :)

Comment: Answer my question. I will mark it as correct, if you want :)